# Odoo How to Make Module Auto Install When Starting for the First Time

Tags: module, automation, odoo

I have downloaded and imported some modules from a third party. I put these modules in separate folder `libs`. When I start the Odoo for the first time, I want these modules automatically install. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a module, lets called `my_setup_module`, that holds all the third party modules as it's dependencies, and when you first start odoo you have to add this parameter `-i my_setup_module` to be installed. For the next server restarts this parameter isn't need it anymore.

I hope this answer can be helpful for you.